# XXXX before a @Model in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I currently have the following in my code

```
<span>XXXX @Model.primary.cardNumber4</span>
```

This Outputs:
`XXXX 1234"

I want to remove the space between `XXXX` and the card number. I tried the following:

```
<span>XXXX@Model.primary.cardNumber4</span>
```

This Outputs:
`XXXX@Model.primary.cardNumber4`

How do i correctly remove the space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the space between the text and the `@` but you must surround the code with parentheses so Razor interprets it as code instead of text:

```
<span>XXXX@(Model.primary.cardNumber4)</span>
```